# Azure with single web app, but point different domans to it (NOT subdomains)

Tags: azure, dns

Is it possible to have multiple domains pointing to a single azure web app?

If so is there any reason this would not be recommended (maybe SEO)?

thanks.
voss.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have multiple domains pointing to single azure web app.

[image]